# vimscript - copy a file from one path to another

Tags: vimscript, filesystem

How do I rewrite this line of code

```
call system("cp /tmp/foo.txt /tmp/bar.txt")
```

into a vim command which is more portable and OS-independent?

I've been looking around but checking for "vimscript copy file / folder" surprisingly doesn't show any results.

**Important**: I need to also know how to copy folders using vimscript, too. Not make a new folder, but copy one which already exists.

Comment: I know there is an excerpt in `:h writefile()` detailing copying files, no idea for folders.

Comment: Might take a look at tpope’s eunuch plugin for inspiration